# Spring JPA - Chamada de Procedure com sqlserver dialect

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Olá,

tenho a seguinte configuração no meu arquivo application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Porém, quando executo uma chamada de procedure o JPA utiliza `CALL` ao invés de `EXEC`:

```
Hibernate: {call SPT_BUSCA_DADOS_VENDEDOR(?)}

Hibernate: {call SPT_LE_HTK_TEMP_PED(?)}
```

isso está causando alguns problemas em chamadas de procedure.
existe alguma forma para alterar a maneira como as procedures são chamadas?

Comment: Como está fazendo esta chamada no JPA?